# Subclass from UIView or UIImageView? Overthinking a simple image downloading task.

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview, uiimageview

This question is two fold:

**1) Understanding which subclass method is better when creating an `Asynchronous download ImageView` class**

**2) And how to use this class in a UITableViewController so that the class view is automatically adopted in a `UITableViewCell`.**

---

**Task at hand**

I just received a fun little task from someone but I'm overthinking the solution.

[image]

**Question 1 - Which method is better for my purposes?**

Keeping in mind that I will have to reuse the class to display some images perhaps in a `UITableViewController`, I thought about two possible ways of going about implementing such a class:

**1)** Either create a class that subclasses from `UIView`, then add the required `imageURL` property, and then also add a `UIImageView` property container to this subclass which the image will download into once the asychronous request has been downloaded once the user set the URL property when he is to "re-use" the class in a table view controller.

Or

**2)** Create a class subclassing from `UIImageView` and then only add that one required property `imageURL` which would then save me the mess of having to progammatically create an image container.

**Question 2: Whats the best way to `re-use` this `Asynchronous ImageView class` that I have created in a UITableViewController.**

The problem (at least what I believe may be a stumbling block) is when I create the table view controller, whats the best way to have this image set the image property of a UITableView cell?

something like

```
AsynchronousImageViewDownloader *myImageView = [[AsynchronousImageViewDownloader alloc] init];
[myImageView setImageURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"url.com/image.jpg"]];
//At this point im not sure how to have the image display in the image property below.
//Remember that the image should automatically show in the view when the url has been set.

cell.image = ??
```

How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: If you want to have the image downloaded when the url is set, then you override the setter for that property, and put your download code there. I see no reason you should use a UIView for this task, a subclassed UIImageView would be simpler.

Comment: @rdelmar Hey, I totally know how to start the URL based on when the imageURL property is set. I guess you answered question 1, to use a subclass of UIImageView, for that I thank you. But now remainds question two, once the image has been downloaded through my completion block, how would I then have this image show in a UITableViewCells image property by RE-USING the custom imageView class I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and add a public property to that class for your `AsynchronousImageViewDownloader` imageView. In init, create the imageview (it will not have a URL at this time) and add it to `self.contentView`.

Then in cellForRow you'll be able to do something like

`cell.customImageView.url = @"someURL"`

Comment: and I've got to subclass a UITableViewCell? I cant just use the default cell and have it's image property use my custom class?

Comment: the default cell uses a standard UIImageView (not an image), and it is not advisable to remove it at runtime or modify its behavior at runtime. If your image downloader could be reworked into a category on UIImageView, you might be able to get the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: Ah you're right. Otherwise, yes exactly. I did think of using a category class but unfortunately you cant use instance variables in a category class unless you start using associated references. #canGetUglyForASimpleTask.

Comment: Btw @nick, you answered question 2. How about question 1? Would subclassing from `UIImageView` be the way forward or `UIView`? I have to ensure an image container is there but to then also display a `UIActivityIndicatorView` while the image is loading. Will it be ugly if I add a subview on top of the `UIImageView` or is the "appropriate" way to add the `UIActivityIndicatorView` on `UIView` which would mean I would have to subclass and then create another property but for an image container for the image to download into and then manage its frame. :S eeks! lol

Comment: I think it will be ok for the test to add a subview to the `UIImageView` if I to subclass from a `UIImageView` right?

Comment: While I understand the urge to use the most generic class possible, you really want to use UIImageView because you need a reference to self.image. There is no problem adding adding an activity indicator as a subview, it is a very 'normal' thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

Create `UIImageView` subclass with a single new property, imageURL. In the subclass's implementation, override `setImageURL` with something similar to the following:

```
- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    if (!_imageURL) {
        _imageURL = imageURL;
        // Do asynchronous image download, setting the self.image property, on the main thread, in the completion block.
    }

    return _imageURL;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding but please read the question again. The problem was never with executing an asynchronous request.

Comment: I've merely provided a simple implementation that meets your criteria of being able to start the image download when the URL property is set. My real recommendation would be to use AFNetworking with its UIImageView category but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: Jshier, you are not answering my question at all. I am aware of all these implementations. You have chosen to avoid answering the question at hand. The OP - me - an asking you to address two questions related to subclassing and adopting a custom class in a  custom `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I thought you were aware of how to use `UITableViewCell` and just asking where an asynchronous image downloader should live. If you're not sure how to use this custom class in a cell, follow Nick's answer and create a custom cell subclass with the image view subclass as a subview. You would then assign the URL in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Please delete this answer as this does not aim to address the question. Thank you buddy.